# Why $a^mb^nc^p....$ depends on $\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^{m}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)^{p} \ldots$ for being the greatest?

Tags: inequality

I am studying Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight and not much explanation is given on any article. So, I had some doubts on this article.

> **To find the greatest value of $a^mb^nc^p....$ when $a+b+c+.....$ is constant; $m,n,p.....$ being positive integers.**
>
> Since $m,n,p.....$ are constants the expression $a^mb^nc^p....$ will be greatest when $\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^{m}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)^{p} \ldots$ is greatest.
> (For complete article an image is attached)
> [image]

**Now, here I am not able to understand why $a^mb^nc^p....$ depends on $\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^{m}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)^{p} \ldots$ for being the greatest?**

**Also, can anyone please explain how the author got $m^{n} n^{n} p^{p} \ldots\left(\frac{a+b+c+\ldots}{m+n+p+\ldots}\right)^{m+n+p+\ldots}$ as the greatest value?**

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: You might also notice that there is a typo in the book,  the exponential of $m$ in the last row of the exercise should be $m$ and not $n$   .

Comment: Yes, There are many typos in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $ m^m n^n \ldots $ is a constant, so you can multiply/divide/add/subtract it and still retain the relative sizing.

---

AM-GM gives the equality condition easily. Did they talk about it before?

Comment: Yes, they did talk about it before, but why did they take $\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^{m}\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^{n}\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)^{p} \ldots$ in the first place?

Comment: It was done in order to apply the condition that $a+b+c ...$ is constant. If you tried to do AM-GM directly, you will end up with $ma+nb+pc+...$, which you have no control over.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since $m,n,k,\dots$ are constant, $a^mb^nc^k\dots$ is $(a/m)^m(b/n)^n\dots$ multiplied by a (positive) constant. So one is maximum iff the other is. Then AM-GM inequality:

$$\begin{aligned}
&\phantom{=} a + b + \cdots \\
&=\underbrace{a/m + a/m + \cdots + a/m}_m + \underbrace{b/n + b/n + \cdots + b/n}_n + \cdots \\
&\ge ...
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: That was explained by my first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the Hall-Knight Higher Algebra book, came across this section a couple of days ago and had the same question. Anyway, answering your questions:

> Now, here I am not able to understand why $a^mb^nc^p\cdots$ depends on $\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^m\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^n\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)^p\cdots$ for being the greatest?

It doesn't.

Since $m^mn^np^p\cdots$ is a constant value, say $k$, **maxing out $\frac{a^mb^nc^p\cdots}{k}$ implies maxing out $a^mb^nc^p\cdots$** and it helps with algebraic gymnastics to arrive at the required solution.

But approaching the solution from this angle does not help much as I experienced.

---

> Also, can anyone please explain how the author got $m^mn^np^p\cdots\left(\frac{a+b+c+\cdots}{m+n+p+\cdots}\right)^{m+n+p+\cdots}$ as the greatest value?

Fellow victim of Hall-Knight Higher Algebra text book, I shall help thee...

Since the book says $a+b+c+\cdots$ is a constant, we shall denote it by $s$
$$
a+b+c+\cdots=s
$$

This can be re-written as,
$$
\begin{aligned}
s&=m\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)+n\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)+p\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)+\cdots \\
&=\underbrace{\left(\frac{a}{m}+\frac{a}{m}+\cdots\right)}_\text{$m \text{ times}$} + 
\underbrace{\left(\frac{b}{n}+\frac{b}{n}+\cdots\right)}_\text{$n \text{ times}$} +
\underbrace{\left(\frac{c}{p}+\frac{c}{p}+\cdots\right)}_\text{$p \text{ times}$} + \cdots
\end{aligned} 
$$

From the general AM-GM inequality we have,
$$
\left(\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_r}{r}\right)^r \geq a_1a_2\cdots a_r
$$
Applying this to the previous equation on $s$, we get
$$
\left(\frac{\frac{a}{m}+\frac{a}{m}+\cdots+\frac{b}{n}+\frac{b}{n}+\cdots+\frac{c}{p}+\frac{c}{p}+\cdots}{m+n+p+\cdots}\right)^{m+n+p+\cdots} \geq \left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^m\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^n\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)^p\cdots
$$

Notice that the numerator on the LHS is $s$. Upon simplification we get,
$$
m^mn^np^p\cdots\times\left(\frac{a+b+c+\cdots}{m+n+p+\cdots}\right)^{m+n+p+\cdots} \geq a^mb^nc^p\cdots
$$

From the above result, it is clear that the max. value of $a^mb^nc^p\cdots$ is
$$
m^mn^np^p\cdots\left(\frac{a+b+c+\cdots}{m+n+p+\cdots}\right)^{m+n+p+\cdots}
$$
and we're done.

PS: I personally think that starting the solution by maxing out $\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^m\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)^n\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)^p\cdots$ is a bit confusing.